# Couldn't rollback ado.net connection, transaction was not connected or disconnected error - quartz.net

Tags: quartz.net

I am getting the transaction error and my quartz scheduler seems to be stuck and I have to restart it for it to go again. Just wondering if there is some retry setting that I can use.

Quartz version: 3.0.7

```
2019-09-23 07:20:20.0654||ERROR|Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.ConnectionAndTransactionHolder|Couldn't rollback ADO.NET connection. Transaction not connected, or was disconnected System.InvalidOperationException: Transaction not connected, or was disconnected
   at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.ConnectionAndTransactionHolder.CheckNotZombied()
   at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.ConnectionAndTransactionHolder.Rollback(Boolean transientError)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already retry logic in place, but apparently it has a bug in it. I was going to report the issue but it had already been reported. Though I added a bit of clarification on how this issue is happening:

https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/794

**Update**

This has been fixed in Quartz 3.1.0

https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/releases/tag/v3.1.0

```
Fix potential scheduler deadlock caused by changed lock request id inside ExecuteInNonManagedTXLock (#794)
```